# Find the distance traveled if the velocity is given. I want to confirm my reasoning

Tags: calculus, word-problem

I wanted to make sure about something. My velocity function is given as $ v(t)=e^{-kt}$ for some fixed k>0. I am asked to find the distance traveled from t=0 to t=10 if the initial position is at x=0. My question is, I don't really need the initial position right? I just need to integrate the velocity from 0 to 10?  I would need the initial position to find the position of the particle at t=10 but not the distance traveled? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  If I tell you I was driving at $60$ mph for ten minutes, you know I drove $10$ miles.  You don't need to know where I started.

Comment: Perhaps they meant displacement. Otherwise it doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answers, also what is the difference in displacement and distance in this case? They are the same?

Comment: Distance could be considered a non-negative quantity. When the term "displacement" is used, it clearly indicates that the quantity may be positive or negative. In that sense, "displacement" is less ambiguous than "distance."

Comment: Thank you, here in this example they are the same tho correct?